# then() returning a null value when it should be pending

Tags: javascript, ember.js, promise, ember-data

Ember 2.17

I am calling an helper from my template :

```
{{#each invoice.invoiceLines as |line| }}
  {{pricings/full-pricing line.pricing}}
{{/each}}
```

`invoice`,`invoiceLine`, as well as `pricing` are ember models.

Here is how invoice is created in model () :

```
model(params) {
    let invoice= this.store.findRecord('invoice',params.invoice_id)
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      invoice: invoice,
      allShares: invoice.then((i)=>{return i.allShares()}),
      detailShares: invoice.then((i)=>{return i.detailShares()})
    });
  }
```

The goal of the helper is to take pricing, extract numbers (everything is in the model, no more relations) and return a string formatting the initial price and the subscription price.
The helper is as following :

```
import { helper } from '@ember/component/helper';

export function pricingsFullPricing([pricing]) {
  return pricing.then(
    p=>{
      debugger
    },p=>{

    }
  )
}
export default helper(pricingsFullPricing);
```

When I run the page, debugger is called twice (the template loop run once).

First time p is null, the second time it is a pricing.

Isn't `then` supposed to prevent that? Why does it behave like that?

Comment: what is the file location of your helper?

Comment: helpers/pricings/full-pricing.js

Comment: what is the value of `invoice.invoiceLines`? before your loop, can you put {{log invoice.invoiceLines}} and {{debugger}} in the template?

Comment: log of invoice.inlines : 
https://i.imgur.com/BTLEMQD.png

Comment: hmm, I don't know what any of that is -- can you use this? https://github.com/fivetanley/ember-promise-helpers and then work with a more regular object after it's awaited?

Comment: I had a similar solution in mind before asking the question, but I would like to understand what is happening.

Comment: You're missing a `return` before the `pricing.then`.

Comment: What is `invoice.invoiceLines`? Where is this initiated?

Answer (score 2):

Your route is wrong, routes are promise aware (that's what `hash` is for), it should be:

```
model(params) {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      invoice: this.store.findRecord('invoice',params.invoice_id)
      //allShares: invoice.then((i)=>{return i.allShares()}),
      //detailShares: invoice.then((i)=>{return i.detailShares()})
    });
  }
```

Then your handlebars is just:

```
{{#each model.invoice.invoiceLines as |line| }}
  {{line}}
{{/each}}
```

You also shouldn't call methods like you are on a model. It's not really clear what `allShares()`, etc does but these should (probably) be `computed` in the **controller**. Something along the lines of:

```
import { computed } from '@ember/object';

export default Controller.extend({
   allShares:computed('model.invoice', function(){
       return this.get('model.invoice').allShares();
   });
});
```

Though this doesn't seem ideal. Like I said, it's hard to be explicit as it's not clear what your trying to do here. It'd probably make more sense if your **extracted these methods into a [service](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/applications/services/)**.

**You then don't need the helper at all.** This appears to be just trying to work around promises.

It makes life a lot easier if you try and load **all server side data** in the `route` before load.

Comment: The share functions are not related to my problem, but thanks for the input. It is custom model function that are used to retrieve tabular data related to the model. I end up displaying them in tables.

Comment: @Syl But the whole reason you've structured your route the way you have is because of the share functions. Ultimately that is the design decision that has caused this issue. This is essentially an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: What happen when I get `null` is that it solve the hash and return `null` because the second promise (invoice as a variable) should have been called inside the `RSVP` hash ?

Comment: `if (model.invoice !== null)` seems like the obvious solution

Comment: Or even just get your invoice call to return all the data you need in one go. Without multiple hops to the server. If `allShares` needs an invoice you could easily argue that it is part of `invoice` and should be loaded with it

Answer (score 2):

First rule of helpers

> Each time the input to a helper changes, the compute function will be called again.

Second, there's nothing about helpers that will make this block subsequent calls because you are returning a promise.

```
export function pricingsFullPricing([pricing]) {
  return pricing.then(
    p=>{
      debugger
    },p=>{

    }
  )
}
```

You've created a simple helper here that will use the promise itself as the value. Look at [ember-promise-helpers/await](https://github.com/fivetanley/ember-promise-helpers/blob/master/addon/helpers/await.js) to see how a [class based helper](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/templates/writing-helpers/#toc_class-based-helpers) is used to manually set the value that's displayed in the template.

Now, if you're wondering why the recomputation is happening, I'm going to have to speculate based off the knowledge I have of Ember data just from being part of the Ember community (I've never actually used Ember Data). You know `line.pricing` is a promise? I can then assume your using some sort of relationship, which will most likely have to be loaded via an ajax call (hence the promise). But these relationships in Ember data, iirc, use this [PromiseProxyMixin](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/release/classes/PromiseProxyMixin) that allow them to behave simultaneously like a promise or like an object (depending on whether the data is in the store already or not). This is what allows you to reference the promise in your template without `then`

See this [article](https://embermap.com/notes/83-the-case-against-async-relationships) for a better understanding of what I mean

Comment: *I've never actually used Ember Data* that is the best way to be. Worst part of Ember IMO

Comment: It wasn't 1.0 when I started Ember.  Nowadays, I think ED has done a very good job solving this difficult problem in a general way. I just still find the benefit to complexity ratio heavily skewed in the direction of "do I really need a full fledged client side ORM?" I use semantically named services + my own relationship aware recursive deserializers/serializers + a promise returning wrapper "rest-client" that makes the http requests and knows how to communicate with my backend. Any new Ember dev that knows js groks the architecture without trying b/c its so explicit